# Iterating over files in a folder (Windows machine)

Tags: command-prompt, loops

I wrote a command to iterate a certain operation over all the files in a folder. It works perfectly from shel on a linux machine but I cannot make it working on a windows machine....and I need to make it working on a Windows one. The command looks like this:

```
ls |grep -v _output| while read file; do ..\..\..\program.exe [option] ..\..\input_file "$file" > "$file"_output; done
```

I get errors with `ls` and `while` and `grep`.
Any suggestion is very welcome!

Gab

Answer (score 1):

ls, while, and grep are not natively supported by Windows. I would suggest installing Cygwin; if that's not an option, the machines you need to run this on may have PowerShell installed.

Comment: That's true...I didn't know how to avoid that. Thank you.